# Getting an error when attempting to change the path written in CMakeLocal.Local is located

Tags: bash, vim

So I'm trying to change the path written in CMakeLocal.Local to where the FFTW is actually installed. However, I get a syntax error:

[image]

I assume the error is due to the text editor but I've used vi/vim before so there shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: This is just a shell usage issue; what do you think `(FFTW_LIBRARIES "/mnt/c/libfftw3.a")` will do?

Comment: @Linus: You have to read the error message carefully: It says _**bash**: syntax error_, and not _**vi**: syntax error_. You can provoke the same error by typing, i.e. `x (Y)`. I don't know what you wanted to achieve here, but the parenthesis simply don't make any sense.

Comment: @chepner editing the path in CMakeLocal to where fftw is installed.

Comment: That's not how `vi`, or any text editor, works.

Comment: If that's the *only* line in the entire file, you may as well just overwrite it with the desired line: `printf 'set (FFTW_LIBRARIES) "%s"\n' "/mnt/c/libfftw3.a" > CMakeLocal.cmake`, rather than trying to edit it.

Comment: @chepner shouldn't the path be inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @Linus Yes. `printf 'set (FFTW_LIBRARIES "%s")\n' "/mnt/c/libfftw3.a" ...`